# Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I facing this error even though I had created my own according to this website [Creating Notification Channels in Flutter (Android)](https://rechor.medium.com/creating-notification-channels-in-flutter-android-e81e26b33bec)

> Notification Channel requested (myapp.com/notification) has not been created by the app. Manifest configuration, or default, value will be used.
>
> Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.

In the same directory as the MainActivity.kt, I also created another file name Application.kt

```
package com.myapp

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
        io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
    }
}
```

Can anyone show me where is the problems and the solution?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: currently no...